# How to disable ipv6 in Centos

Tags: nginx, centos, droplet

Please i need help disabling ipv6 in my digitalcoean droplet. I followed the tutorial here https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/ipv6/how-to/enable/#on-existing-droplets and enabled one in my production ready app. We app went live hours ago, and i enabled the ipv6 thinking its not gonna affect the config. It did and now my site is down returning 502 , bad gateway. I have tried everything possible . Right now i just want to disable it and have my ipv4 in place, this too has proven difficult . I enable witha button click, but there is no disable option. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain the configuration for CentOS, first you have to go to the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` add or change the following line:

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
```

Next, edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, which specifies how the network should be configured when it is opened, here you comment on all the IPv6 information. And finally this file also sets the DNS directives to point to the IPv6 name servers.

```
DNS1=
DNS2=
...
```

And reboot the system.